# Java: recieve a list of lists containing tuples from python script over TCP

Tags: java, android, python

I have a python script that I would like to send a list of lists that contains tuples of integers to an android application over a TCP connection. To achieve that, I am pickling the list and then I send it. The problem is in the android app side that I am receiving the data and I am unpickling it with `Unpickler` from `net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler` but I don't know how to recover the initial structure.
This method worked when I was trying to send a list of strings and it worked fine with the below code as I printed the elements of the list in Logcat.
**Java:**

```java
Unpickler unpickler = new Unpickler();
in.read(buffer);
Object t= (Object) unpickler.loads(buffer);
List<String> strs = (Arraylist<String>) t;
```

I tried the same with a list of lists containing tuples of integers as below( I used `Pair` from `android.util`):

```java
Unpickler unpickler = new Unpickler();
in.read(buffer);
Object t= (Object) unpickler.loads(buffer);
List<ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> coords = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>>) t;
```

I tried printing the first number of tuples in list:

```java
for (ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>> coordsPair: finalCoords){
    for(Pair<Integer,Integer> coord: coordsPair) {
        Log.d("coordinates: ",""+coord.first);
    }
}
```

But I didn't get any result in Logcat as the typecast of `unpickler.loads(buffer)` didn't work.
Is this way wrong to regain the initial structure of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to find a solution:
First of all I changed the way I am receiving the pickled data by replacing `in.read(buffer);` with the following block:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream bff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];
byte[] pickledStream;
while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    bff.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
pickledStream = bff.toByteArray();
```

Then, I saved the unpickled data to an `Object t` and then I passed the `t` to  `List<ArrayList<Object[]>>` instead of `List<ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>>`  as the python tuples can be recognized as an Object.

```java
Object t = unpickler.loads(pickledStream);
List<List<Object[]>> finalCoords= (List<List<Object[]>>) t;
```